# Position navbar on the vertical center of a div

Tags: html, css, icons, center, nav

I need to do something like this:

[image]

I have written this code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}" class="menu__item" data-tooltip="Home">
        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('about') }}" class="menu__item" data-tooltip="About">
        <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('skills') }}" class="menu__item" data-tooltip="Skills">
        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('projects') }}" class="menu__item" data-tooltip="Projects">
        <i class="material-icons">work</i>
      </a>
      <a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}" class="menu__item" data-tooltip="Contact">
        <i class="material-icons">email</i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    margin-left: 75px;
}

.nav{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #181818;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu{
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu__item{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}
```

However, the navbar is still showing up at the top of the parent div:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? What am I doing wrong. I usually don't work in html and css so this is probably something quite simple.

NOTE: I am using a python framework to manage the html so don't question the `{% %}` parts in the code. They are not the reason this is not working.

Comment: No, I am trying to vertically center a <nav>

Comment: its the exact same technique

Comment: I have already seen this question before posting my question, it simply doesn't help due to the nature of the navbar and parent div. I'm still open to answers if you're willing to test this yourself.

Comment: instead of usign `nav` you could use `div` or wrapp it into an extra div and vertically center that wrapper div. Plenty ways makign that solution work in your case. What else is rpevent you from doing it?

Comment: How could I vertically center it?

Comment: sorry was a wrong link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, I'll see if this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm. What should I do to this question now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223567/discussion-between-faizan-shah-and-tacoshy).